# how i can insert photo delails to database?

Tags: database, model-view-controller, controller, action, dropzone.js

i want send parameters category , objid and city  to action index and index page use Drop zone  select multi image in drop zone and i want insert category  , objid and image name with stored procedure insert to database 
now one image delails save in database
help me ?

this code send parameters:

```
@Html.ActionLink("اپلود تصویر", "index", "Pictures", new { objid = item.Id, cityid = item.CityId, category = item.CategoryId }, null)
```

and index code :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int? objid, int? cityid, int? category)
        {

           if (objid != null )
            {
                TempData["id"] = objid;
                TempData["city"] = cityid;
                TempData["category"] = category;

            }

            bool isSavedSuccessfully = true;
            string fName = "";

                        foreach (string fileName in Request.Files)
                        {
                            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[fileName];
                            //Save file content goes here
                            fName = file.FileName;
                            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                            {

                                var originalDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(string.Format("{0}Images\\UploadImages", Server.MapPath(@"\")));
                                string pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(originalDirectory.ToString(), "imagepath");
                                var myUniqueFileName = string.Format(@"{0}", Guid.NewGuid());
                                var fileName1 =  Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                                var fileName2= Path.GetFileName(myUniqueFileName+file.FileName);
                                fileName2= fileName2.Replace("-", "");
                                bool isExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(pathString);
                                file.FileName.Replace(fileName1, fileName2);
                                if (!isExists)
                                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);

                                var path = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", pathString, fileName2);


                                file.SaveAs(path);

                                db.SPInsertPhotoTable(Convert.ToInt32(TempData["city"]), Convert.ToInt32(TempData["category"]), Convert.ToInt32(TempData["id"]), fileName2, "");


                            }
                        }
                        return View();

        }
```